# Creating a trigger that pulls the price from one table and prevents entry into another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

So, I'm kinda an SQL beginner who got himself into a conundrum.

I have a database that's set up with the concept of a luxury goods store. The table `Products` includes the field `Price` which can't be less than $500 (through a trigger). The table `ProductReceipt` has `ID, ProductID, ReceiptID, Amount, Installments`

I want to create a trigger that pulls the price from `Products` and if the price is higher than $600, you can input `True` on `Installments`. If it's lower, then it forces a `False` or rollback into a `False`. This should also take into account the field `Amount`, so if something costs $500, but there's two of said item, the `Installments` option should be applicable.

I'm not sure how exactly to go about it? A `Join`, perhaps?

The Product table contains for example:

`ID: 1,
Name: Rouge Coco
Description: Random Description
Price: $500
CompanyID: 1 (in the Company table, 1 is Chanel)`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  It is not really clear why you need a trigger to do this, so an explanation of why you've decided that is correct would also help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for replying first and foremost! The reason why I went with a trigger is because we received a task to create three database triggers for the database we're designing, and this is the only other (I have two already) spot where I can see a trigger being put without it being a major reuse of old code or something that doesn't make sense in the context of my DB.

As for the data, I'm going to add edit it into the main post.

Comment: @SEarle1986 But it does? There are two tables, ProductReceipt and Product. ProductReceipt columns are in the first paragraph, Product columns are detailed below it.

Comment: Sorry, misread that. I can see it now

Answer (score 1):

As you said you are designing the data, so you can handle this while designing the database only. 
I have tested the following in SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE Products

(Price int
, Installments AS CASE WHEN Price > 600 THEN 'TRUE'

WHEN Price < 600 THEN 'FALSE'

ELSE NULL END
)
```

Comment: This appears to be a constraint?

Comment: @Aragogo it's not a constraint but a computed column, however it assumes that all costs > 600 MUST have installments

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this may not 100% answer the question you as described (does not use triggers) it will do the same job, more efficiently (although I stand to be corrected on that) and with less code

Your reason for using a trigger seems odd, like you have to use three triggers for the sake of using triggers?

Any way, here is the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE ProductReceipt ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Installments CHECK ((Amount > 600 AND Installments IN (1,0)) OR (Amount <= 600 AND Installments = 0))
```

Comment: So, in the Product table, you can't input a price that's lower than $500 because the concept is Luxury products. In the table ProductReceipt, the column Installments is meant to offer payment in Installments if the end price is greater than $600. You can still buy something that costs between 500 and 599, but that won't offer payment in Installments unless you buy two of those cheaper products so the sum price rises up over $600. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    create table Products123
    (
    ID int, 
    Name varchar(10),
    Description varchar(100),
    Price money,
    CompanyID int
    )
```

```
create table ProductReceipt123
( 
ID int, 
ProductID int, 
ReceiptID int, 
Amount money, 
Installments bit
)
```

```
    create TRIGGER tInsert 
       ON  Products123
       AFTER INSERT,DELETE
    AS 
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        Declare @insertedPrice money,@insertedID int

        select @insertedPrice=Price,@insertedID=ID from inserted

        if(@insertedPrice<500)
        Begin
            delete from Products123 where ID=@insertedID

            select 'Price should be greater than 500'
        End

        else if(@insertedPrice>600)
        Begin

            insert into ProductReceipt123(ProductID,Amount,Installments) values(@insertedID,@insertedPrice,1)

        End
        else if(@insertedPrice<600)
        Begin

            insert into ProductReceipt123(ProductID,Amount,Installments) values(@insertedID,@insertedPrice,0)

        End

        -- Insert statements for trigger here

    END
    GO
```

Comment: This looks promising! I'll test it when I get back home in a few hours and reply with the results!

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I intended. It's like a bigger version of the trigger that I use to prevent data entry in the Products table. What I'd like is a trigger that, when I fill out the ProductID and Amount columns in the ProductReceipt table, activates and blocks me from imputting a True to Instalments if the price is lower than 600. So the ProductID product can have a price that is 500 for example, but if there's more than one item in the Amount, it'll allow instalments.